# Hiding Laravel output from user

Tags: php, json, angularjs, laravel-4, response

I am having a little trouble with my Laravel project.

I have made my own API, using Laravel's routing feature, so that I can easily access the database on the client side (angularjs). I have authorization working perfectly and everything else as well, but one thing is bothering me.

Say, for example I have an API route that gets a user's username (after they login of course):

```
Route::get('api/user/username', function(){
     return Response::json(array('username' => Auth::user()->username));
});
```

The output would just be the username, for example:

```
{'username' => 'camrymps'}
```

Now, my issue with this is that the user can still view their username if they go to http://domain.com/api/user/username. What I am trying to do is either provide a 404 error when they go to that URL or some other type of error or even hiding the output from them completely. Basically, I only want the website to retrieve the output, not the user visiting the URL and being able to see their username. Is there any way to make this happen? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not understanding why this is a problem. A RESTful endpoint is just another HTTP resource - regardless of how the user gets to that resource, it should be available. If you only want your website to be able to access that resource, then you can do some IP whitelisting within your app.

Comment: @swatkins, thank you for your response. If I were to do IP whitelisting, would I block all other IP address from accessing the route, except my website's IP?

Comment: Yes, this is assuming you are making the request from your server. If you are making the request by AJAX from the client, then the IP address would be the client IP - which you don't want to block. You would then need to determine that the request is coming from a client machine by way of your website. FWIW, I still don't know why there is a problem with seeing the output directly from the URL.

Comment: Thank you that helps quite a bit! And, I don't really know why it bothers me, I guess it just seems sloppy to me. It is just a pet peeve for me, but if I will try the IP whitelisting. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Well, there can be reasons to limit the accessibility to a resource. I had an API once that we didn't want users to be able to write a program to access, we just wanted them to access via our own application. The key is, find out who/what is making the request and react accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

since JavaScript is a client-side language, you can't supply the information to your JavaScript code but also hide it from the user.

since it's the user machine who make those requests,
any technique you will find would be easily bypass.